# Estimation of ARMA model with alpha-stable power GARCH errors

Tags: time-series, estimation, arima, garch, stable-distribution

I am trying to write the following code for estimating parameters for the ARMA(1,1) with alpha-stable power-GARCH(1,1) (Mittnik et al. (2002)).
My code has 2 problems: 1) estimated parameters have a significant difference with their corresponding true values. 2) Running code takes a long time.

If possible please let me know your guides to overcome problems.

Reference: Mittnik, S., Paollela, M., Rachev, S., (2002). Stationarity of stable power-GARCH processes. Journal of Econometrics, 107, 97-107.

```r
    # Simulating ARMA(1,1) with alpha-stable power-GARCH(1,1). We assumed that delta=1 and mu=0

    library(stabledist)
    library(fBasics)
    alpha1=0.04;beta1=0.9;omega0=.006
    alpha=1.7;beta=-.2;n=1000
    delta=1
    phi=.8;theta=.5
    res1 = rstable(n,alpha,beta,1,0,1)
    sigma=0;sigma[1]=1
    l=length(res1)
    z1=vector()
    z1[1]=sigma[1]/res1[1]
    for (i in (2:l)){
    sigma[i]=omega0+alpha1*abs(z1[i-1])+beta1*sigma[i-1]
    z1[i]=sigma[i]*res1[i]
    }
    x1=0 
    x1[1] = z1[1]
    for(i in (2:l)){
      x1[i] =z1[i] + phi*x1[i-1] + theta*z1[i-1]
    }

    # Estimation of the ARMA(1,1) with alpha-stable power-GARCH(1,1,1) model

    armagarch=function(x){
    m1=1
    phi=.1;theta=.1;alpha1=.1;beta1=.1;omega0=.001
           ;alpha=1.5;beta=.20
    param=c(phi=.1,theta=.1,alpha1=.1,beta1=.1,omega0=.001
           ,alpha=1.5,beta=.20)
    garch_loglik<-function(param){
    #parameters
    phi=param[1]
    theta=param[2]
    alpha1=param[3]
    beta1=param[4]
    omega0=param[5]
    alpha=param[6] 
    beta=param[7]  
    l=length(x)  
    loglik=0
    z=0
    z1[1] = x[1]
    sigma=0
    sigma[1]=1
    res = 0
    res[1]=z1[1]/sigma[1]
    for(j in (2:l)){
    z1[j] = x[j] - phi*x[j-1] - theta*z1[j-1]
      sigma[j]=omega0+alpha1*abs(z1[j-1])+beta1*sigma[j-1]  
      res[j]=z1[j]/sigma[j]
     }
    m1=mean(abs(res))
    result=stableFit(res,type=c("qm"))
    a1=result@fit$estimate
    alpha=a1[1];beta=a1[2]
    loglik=sum(log(dstable(res,alpha,beta,1,0,1)))
    print(c(phi,theta,alpha1,beta1,omega0,alpha,beta))
    print(loglik)
    print(m1)
    return(-loglik)
    }
    bla=nlminb(objective=garch_loglik, 
    start=c(phi,theta,alpha1,beta1,omega0,alpha,beta),
    lower=c(-1,-1,0.001,0.001,0.0001,1.1,-.99),upper=c(1,1,(1-beta1)/m1,1- 
    m1*alpha1,.1,1.99,.99))
    return(bla)
    }
    armagarch(x1)
```

Comment: Title of the question should match with the question. Narrowing down the issue and asking in that direction. (1) What are the true values? (2) Try to profile the code and see where it spends  see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-with-RStudio

Comment: The fastest R implementation of vanilla GARCH is likely the one in the `garchx` package. You may want to look at the source code there to borrow ideas for efficient implementation.